# Adding "all capitals in the question title" to the quality filter

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

So, the guys over in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) have been working on a Smoke Detector that detects potential spam so it can be flagged quicker.

One thing that has been noticed is the number of posts that get raised with an all-caps title. Here are some examples of things that have come through so far today - all three of these posts still exist because they're not actually spam, but they do have titles in all caps

```
[ SmokeDetector ] All-caps title: INSTALLING WINDOWS PROGRAMS AND LEXMARK X4650 PRINTER

[ SmokeDetector ] All-caps title: CAN NOT MAKE A BOOTABLE UBUNTU ISO IMAGE

[ SmokeDetector ] All-caps title: SNORT NOT SHOWING DROPPED/BLOCKED PACKETS
```

Would it be possible to add something into the quality filter that advises users against typing out their titles in all caps?

Comment: WE'RE TALKING ABOUT JUST *TITLES*, RIGHT?  THERE'S A USE CASE FOR QUESTION AND ANSWER BODIES TO BE MAJORITY-CAPITALS.  OTHER THAN LOTS OF YELLING, I MEAN.  IF SO, I'M ALL FOR IT.  MAYBE COMMENTS, TOO.  MIGHT BE A GOOD IDEA, YOU NEVER KNOW.

Comment: WELL I SUPPOSE IT'S PROBABLY A GOOD IDEA TO DO COMMENTS AS WELL, BUT I FIGURED FOR LIKE STACKOVERFLOW THERE IS A POSSIBILITY THAT A LEGITIMATE POST COULD BE MADE IN TERMS OF QUESTIONS WHERE THE MAJORITY OF THE POST IS CAPITAL LETTERS AND NUMBERS (DUE TO ERROR MESSAGES AND WHATNOT)!

Comment: NOT REALLY MUCH OF A DUPE BECAUSE THIS IS EXCLUSIVELY ABOUT TITLES.  AS NOTED IN THE TOP ANSWER THERE, ALL-CAPS BODIES AREN'T TOO HORRIBLY COMMON.  I DO SEE ALL-CAPS TITLES A FEW TIMES A DAY... ALSO COME ON MAN WHERE ARE THE CAPS GET WITH IT.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU ALL WHISPERING SO MUCH? DON'T YOU WANT PEOPLE TO HEAR YOU?

Comment: **I THINK THIS IS A HORRIBLE IDEA. HOW WILL I BE ABLE TO EXPRESS THE URGENCY OF MY PROBLEM IF IT DOESN'T STAND OUT LIKE A SORE THUMB? I PROPOSE WE ONLY IMPLEMENT THIS IF WE ALSO GET `<BLINK></BLINK>` TAGS AS COMPENSATION FOR OUR LOSS**

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.

Comment: THIS IS ABOUT AN ADJUSTMENT TO THE QUALITY FILTERS NOT SO MUCH JUST BLOCKING BUT JUGGLING HOW A SCORE IS RENDERED I DON'T THINK THIS IS REALLY A DUPLICATE THOUGH IT IS SOMEWHAT SIMILAR AND TOUCHING ON THE SAME GROUND.

Comment: I'M RATHER TEMPTED TO SUGGEST AN EDIT CHANGING THE TITLE TO ALL CAPS

Comment: @RALZAREK DO IT!

Comment: ***`VOTE RETRACTED`***

Comment: STOP YELLING Y'ALL! Regarding the point brought up about expressing urgency, I think this is pretty subjective, what is urgent to one isn't quite important to all of us, and remember, reading lower-case (Sentence case) is proven to be the easiest to humans... well, humans only, not monkeys :)

Comment: @Ayyash SPEAK FOR YOURSELF HOOMAN! (though you might need to glance at my profile picture)

Comment: @Ayyash: I THINK THE POINT ABOUT URGENCY WAS A MERE JOKE! THERE ARE PEOPLE OUT THERE WHO BELIEVE THAT EXPRESSING URGENCY WITH ALL-CAPS **ON THE INTERNET** IS SOMETHING THAT WORKS! ... ALSO IF YOU'D EXCUSE ME, I NOW NEED TO BURN MY KEYBOARD AND HANDS FOR WRITING THIS!

Comment: @everyone ur caps r on, btw

Comment: @BilltheLizard: [Never, ever, tell people about the caps lock key!](http://bash.org/?835030) ... I think that should be first rule of The Internet or something.

Comment: That's no monkey, @TimPost. That's an ape.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT TITLES THAT ARE mostly ALL-CAPS???  SHOULD this BE FILTERED TOO?

Comment: If a question or answer has lots of CAPS, they should probably be confined to code blocks. Lots of caps in plain text should be considered suspicious (although it could just be a user not knowing how to create code blocks properly).

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby no... that's the 3rd rule.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose the concern with adding an all-caps quality filter would be whether any legitimate all-caps titles could be removed. To check whether this was the case, I pulled together quick StackExchange Data Explorer queries to find all the questions with all-caps titles on [StackOverflow (2,010 total results)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352532/all-caps-posts-on-so), [CrossValidated (3 total results)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/352535/all-caps-posts-on-crossvalidated), and [Mathematics (13 results)](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/352537/all-caps-posts-on-mathematics).

The vast majority of these questions were examples like the one in the question, where somebody got overzealous with the shift key. Other than that, it's basically just code or mathematical expressions in titles.

[SQL: … WHERE X IN (SELECT Y FROM …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956048/sql-where-x-in-select-y-from)

[SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016168/select-from-table-where-1-2)

[INSERT INTO … VALUES (…) WHERE NOT EXISTS (…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813488/insert-into-values-where-not-exists)

[1 %% 0.1 = 0.1 AND 1 %% 0.2 = 0.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546439/1-0-1-0-1-and-1-0-2-0-2)

[(A <-> B) -> A = B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327767/a-b-a-b)

[P(Y >84 | Y > 72) =?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729794/py-84-y-72)

[CP(2) = SU(3)/U(2)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944847/cp2-su3-u2)

[A - (B-C) = (A-B) ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098276/a-b-c-a-b-%E2%88%AA-a-%E2%88%A9-b-%E2%88%A9-c)

Given that none of these appear to be particularly high-quality titles, this seems like a great filter to add!

Comment: Do any of those resemble good question titles?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The given examples are awful titles, and the site would be better off without them. We strongly discourage formula-only titles. "A - (B-C) = (A-B) ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)" is not searchable. Something like "Express nested set difference in terms of unions and intersections" would be way better.

Comment: @NormalHuman oh... I thought the last one was legit... but yeah I guess it wouldn't be searchable! :/  *deletes comment and runs*

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that just lead to titles like:

```
URGENT - HOMEWORK DO NOW !!! FIX MY CODE ok???

Is A - (B-C) = (A-B) ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)

How SQL: … WHERE X IN (SELECT Y FROM …)

cODE NOT WORKING
```

Comment: NO, BECAUSE IT WILL BE PERCENTILE BASED, SOMETHING LIKE "IF 50% IS ALL CAPS"

Comment: oKaY tHaT mAkEs SeNsE

Comment: Every filter can be worked around, as spammers demonstrate to us daily. The message would have some effect on people who honestly think that formatting  titles in all caps is how it should be done.

Comment: @NormalHuman yes, I agree.  Just wanted to see if thought was given to percent vs ALL caps